# Using actionbar home as up button, home activity saveInstanceState is always null

Tags: android, android-actionbar

Activity A ===click button===> Activity B

When press back button, Activity A is not recreated.

When press home as up button, Activity A is recreated.

So I save state when A.onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) 
, and use state when A.onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState).

Saving and Using works fine (except home as up button)

.

However,

When pressed home as up button, 
system recreate Activity A, and savedInstanceState is gone.

How can I use Saved Instance State?

```
    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case android.R.id.home:
        // I do not want this... 
        // Home as up button is to navigate to Home-Activity not previous acitivity
            super.onBackPressed();
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
```

Comment: @ArunCThomas  "Home as up button is to navigate to Home-Activity not previous acitivity" If other pakage app start Activity B and user press up button, must show Activity A (Because A is home of B).

Answer (score 60, accepted):

In the onCreate() enable the home button.

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ...
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
}
```

In the onOptionItemSelected() method do this.

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    // Respond to the action bar's Up/Home button
    case android.R.id.home:
        NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this);
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

This should enable Up navigation. If you want the parent activity to be restored with a savedInstanceState. You should set `launchMode="singleTop"` in the parent activity in Manifest file.

For more info check out [http://developer.android.com/: Providing Up Navigation](http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/ancestral.html)

Comment: I still can't get this to work as desired as the up navigation will recreated the parent activity with no saved state, is there something special about how you start your activities?

Comment: on parent activity you should set launchmode="singleTop"

Comment: `NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this)` this results in `NullPointerException` if the `Activity` is being launched directly from some other application!

Comment: I got the desired behavior solely by adding `launchMode="singleTop"` to the parent activity in the AndroidManifest.

Comment: You don't typically need to provide an implementation for `onOptionsItemSelected`. To quote the official docs: "You do not need to catch the up action in the activity's onOptionsItemSelected() method. Instead, that method should call its superclass, as shown in Respond to Actions. The superclass method responds to the Up selection by navigating to the parent activity, as specified in the app manifest." https://developer.android.com/training/appbar/up-action.html

Comment: launchMode="singleTop" is enough

Answer (score 32):

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    // Respond to the action bar's Up/Home button
    case android.R.id.home:
        finish();
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

I used **finish()** insteed of **NavUtils**;

Comment: Can someone confirm that this is the right method ?

Comment: @Mehdiway Yes this is right. Or you can call `onBackPressed()` as well.

Comment: Note: There is a difference between `R.id.home` and `android.R.id.home`.

Answer (score 0):

As @Joachim mentioned in a comment, there is a difference between `R.id.home` and `android.R.id.home`. In my case, I have been using `R.id.home`, which did not work, and `android.R.id.home` did work.