# how to keep edittext values when you go back

Tags: android, android-edittext

I have made a Fibonacci calculator app. When I use my floating action button back button the values are kept. However, when I press the back arrow on my titlebar the values are gone. My manifest is like this:

```
<activity android:name=".FibonacciActivity">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>

</activity>
<activity
    android:name=".FibonacciResults"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
    android:label="@string/Uptrend"
    android:parentActivityName=".FibonacciActivity" >
    <meta-data
        android:name="android.support.PARENT ACTIVITY"
        android:value=".FibonacciActivity" />
</activity>
```

My Java class:

```
 public class FibonacciResults extends FibonacciActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_fibonacci_results);
        TextView retracement0 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtRetracement0);
        TextView retracement1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtRetracement1);
        TextView retracement2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtRetracement2);
        extension1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtExt1);
        TextView extension2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtExt2);
        getIntent().getExtras();
        String strRetracement0 = bundle.getString("Retracement0");
        String strRetracement1 = bundle.getString("Retracement1");
        String strRetracement2 = bundle.getString("Retracement2");
        String strExtension1 = bundle.getString("Extension1");
        String strExtension2 = bundle.getString("Extension2");
        retracement0.setText(strRetracement0);
        retracement1.setText(strRetracement1);
        retracement2.setText(strRetracement2);
        extension1.setText(strExtension1);
        extension2.setText(strExtension2); 
    }
    public void onBack(View view) {
        onBackPressed();
    }
}
```

xml:

```
<support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/border"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"


    tools:context="com.bybora.fibonaccicalculator.FibonacciResults">


    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        android:background="@drawable/border"
        android:onClick="onBack"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/back_arrow" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtUpTrend"
        android:layout_width="180dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/default_gap"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/default_gap"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:background="@drawable/border"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="2dp"
        android:text="@string/yükselen_trend"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColor="@color/navyBlue"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/extensions"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/extensions"
        android:layout_width="180dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:background="@drawable/border"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="2dp"
        android:text="@string/extensions"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColor="@color/navyBlue"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/txtUpTrend"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/txtUpTrend"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/txtUpTrend"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="196dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtPer236"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="0dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="0dp"
        android:background="@drawable/border"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="2dp"
        android:text="@string/percent_236"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColor="@color/navyBlue"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/txtRetracement0"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/txtRetracement0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/txtUpTrend"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/txtUpTrend" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtRetracement0"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="0dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="0dp"
        android:background="@drawable/border"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="2dp"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColor="@color/red"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/txtUpTrend"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/txtPer236"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/txtUpTrend" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtExt2618"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
        android:background="@drawable/border"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="2dp"
        android:text="@string/percent2618"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColor="@color/navyBlue"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/txtPer236"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/txtExt1"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/extensions"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/extensions" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtExt1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:background="@drawable/border"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="2dp"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColor="@color/red"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/txtExt2618"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/extensions"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/txtExt2618"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/extensions"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="291dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtPer382"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/border"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="2dp"
        android:text="@string/percent382"
        android:textColor="@color/navyBlue"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@id/txtPer236"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/txtUpTrend"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/txtPer236" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtRetracement1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
        android:background="@drawable/border"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="2dp"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColor="@color/red"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/txtPer382"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/txtUpTrend"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/txtRetracement0"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/txtRetracement0" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtExt200"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:background="@drawable/border"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="2dp"
        android:text="@string/percent200"
        android:textColor="@color/navyBlue"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/txtPer382"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/txtExt1"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@id/extensions"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/extensions"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/txtExt2618" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtExt2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:background="@drawable/border"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="2dp"
        android:textColor="@color/red"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/txtPer382"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/extensions"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/txtExt200"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/txtExt1" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtPer50"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/border"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="2dp"
        android:text="@string/percent50"
        android:textColor="@color/navyBlue"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/txtRetracement0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/txtUpTrend"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/txtPer382" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtRetracement2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:background="@drawable/border"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="2dp"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColor="@color/red"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/txtPer50"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/txtUpTrend"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/txtPer50"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/txtRetracement1" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtExt1618"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:background="@drawable/border"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="2dp"
        android:text="@string/percent1618"
        android:textColor="@color/navyBlue"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/txtPer50"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/txtExt1"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/extensions"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/txtExt200" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtExt3"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:background="@drawable/border"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="2dp"
        android:textColor="@color/red"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/txtPer50"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/extensions"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/txtExt1618"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/txtPer50" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtPer618"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/border"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="2dp"
        android:text="@string/percent618"
        android:textColor="@color/navyBlue"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/txtRetracement0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/txtUpTrend"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/txtPer50" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtRetracement3"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:background="@drawable/border"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="2dp"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColor="@color/red"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/txtPer618"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/txtUpTrend"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/txtRetracement0"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/txtRetracement2" />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:background="@drawable/border"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="2dp"
        android:text="@string/percent1382"
        android:textColor="@color/navyBlue"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/txtPer618"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/txtExt3"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/extensions"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/txtPer50"/>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtExt4"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:background="@drawable/border"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="2dp"
        android:textColor="@color/red"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/txtPer618"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/extensions"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/txtExt1"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/txtPer618"/>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtPer786"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/border"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="2dp"
        android:text="@string/percent786"
        android:textColor="@color/navyBlue"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/txtRetracement0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/txtUpTrend"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/txtPer618" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtRetracement4"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:background="@drawable/border"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="2dp"
        android:textColor="@color/red"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/txtPer786"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/txtUpTrend"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/txtRetracement3"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/txtPer786" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtExt100"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:background="@drawable/border"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="2dp"
        android:text="@string/percent100"
        android:textColor="@color/navyBlue"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/txtPer786"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/txtExt1"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/extensions"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/txtPer786" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtExt5"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:background="@drawable/border"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="2dp"
        android:textColor="@color/red"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/txtPer786"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/extensions"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/txtExt1"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/txtPer786" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtPer1382"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/border"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="2dp"
        android:text="@string/percent1382"
        android:textColor="@color/navyBlue"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/txtRetracement0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/txtUpTrend"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/txtPer786" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtRetracement5"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:background="@drawable/border"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="2dp"
        android:textColor="@color/red"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/txtPer1382"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/txtUpTrend"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/txtRetracement0"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/txtPer1382" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtExt618"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:background="@drawable/border"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="2dp"
        android:text="@string/percent618"
        android:textColor="@color/navyBlue"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/txtPer1382"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/txtExt1"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/extensions"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/txtExt100" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtExt6"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:background="@drawable/border"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="2dp"
        android:textColor="@color/red"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/txtPer1382"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/extensions"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/txtExt1"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/txtPer1382" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtPer1618"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/border"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="2dp"
        android:text="@string/percent1618"
        android:textColor="@color/navyBlue"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/txtRetracement0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/txtUpTrend"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/txtPer1382" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtRetracement6"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:background="@drawable/border"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="2dp"
        android:textColor="@color/red"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/txtPer1618"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/txtUpTrend"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/txtRetracement0"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/txtPer1618" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtExt50"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:background="@drawable/border"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="2dp"
        android:text="@string/percent50"
        android:textColor="@color/navyBlue"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/txtPer1618"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/txtExt1"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/extensions"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/txtExt618" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtExt7"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:background="@drawable/border"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="2dp"
        android:textColor="@color/red"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/txtPer1618"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/extensions"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/txtExt1"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/txtExt6" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtExt382"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/border"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="2dp"
        android:text="@string/percent382"
        android:textColor="@color/navyBlue"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/txtExt1"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/txtExt2618"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/txtExt50" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtExt8"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="0dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:background="@drawable/border"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="2dp"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColor="@color/red"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/txtExt382"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/extensions"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/txtExt1"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/txtExt7" />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/border"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="2dp"
        android:text="@string/percent_236"
        android:textColor="@color/navyBlue"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/txtExt1"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/txtExt2618"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/txtExt382" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtExt9"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/border"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="2dp"
        android:textColor="@color/red"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/extensions"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/txtExt1"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/txtExt8" />
    <android.support.constraint.Guideline
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_begin="222dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Keep variables after leaving activity](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23707300/keep-variables-after-leaving-activity)

Comment: Check out my answer if you're still confused give this a read;

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16434445/using-actionbar-home-as-up-button-home-activity-saveinstancestate-is-always-nul

Answer (score 0):

When the "HomeAsUp" button on your Toolbar or ActionBar, the activity you return to is recreated and the savedInstanceState reference to the saved Bundle object is null.

`savedInstanceState = null`

So what we need to do is change what happens when we press the HomeAsUp Button on the Toolbar/ActionBar. We do this by utilising the id of the HomeAsUp button's id that android has provided (android.R.id.home) In the onCreate method make sure;

```
   getSupportActionBar().setHomeAsUpButtonEnabled(true);
   getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
```

In the optionsOnItemSelectedMenu we will add our own code when the HomeAsUpButton is clicked.

```
   public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem menuItem){

        int itemId = menuItem.getId();
        switch(itemId){

             case android.R.id.home:
                     Intent parentIntent = NavUtils.getParentActivityIntent(this);
                     NavUtils.navigateUpTo(this, parentIntent);  
                     return true; 
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(menuItem);
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem by adding

```
public void onBack(View view) {
    onBackPressed();
}
```

to my back button.